# reading a csv.gz file from sagemaker using pyspark kernel mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

i am trying to read a compressed csv file in pyspark. but i am unable to read in pyspark kernel mode in sagemaker.

The same file i can read using pandas when the kernel is conda-python3 (in sagemaker)

What I tried :

```
file1 =  's3://testdata/output1.csv.gz'
file1_df = spark.read.csv(file1, sep='\t')
```

Error message :

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling 104.csv.
: java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 7FF77313; S3 Extended Request ID:
```

Kindly let me know if i am missing anything

Answer (score 1):

> An error was encountered:
> An error occurred while calling 104.csv.
> : java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 7FF77313; S3 Extended Request ID:

There are other Hadoop connectors to S3. Only S3A is actively maintained by the Hadoop project itself.
Apache's Hadoop's original s3:// client. This is no longer included in Hadoop.
Apache's Hadoop's s3n: filesystem client. This connector is no longer available: users must migrate to the newer s3a.

I have attached a document for your reference [Apache S3 Connectors](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/index.md)

PySpark reads gz file automatically as per the document that they have provided.
Click [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html) for the document.

```py
file1 =  's3://testdata/output1.csv.gz'
rdd = sc.textFile(file1)
rdd.take(10)
```

To load files in dataframe

```py
df = spark.read.csv(file1)
```